# Pre-calculation of Geortzel coefficient

Tags: frequency-spectrum

I have found an implementation of the Goertzel algorithm that contains code that I don't understand. And more specifically the pre-calculation of coefficients.

At the top of the code there is :

```
#define DTMF_697Hz  27980
#define DTMF_770Hz  26956
#define DTMF_852Hz  25701
#define DTMF_941Hz  24219
```

These defines are used inside the goertzel calculation like such :

```
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
  v0 = ((cos_fact * v1) >> 14) - v2 + *x;
  x++;
  v2 = v1;
  v1 = v0;
}
```

`x` is my buffer.

`v0`, `v1` and `v2` are `long int`

`cos_fact` is the one of defines I showed above and passed as a function parameter.

My questions would be: What do these define correspond to? How to pre-calculate them for other frequencies? Is it normal that the values are so far apart?

ps: This code is part of `ampm_open_lib` and my goal would be to use it for detecting other frequencies than DTMFs tones.

**EDIT:**

Following the answer of Peter K. Here is a little C program that output the desired values.

```
#include        <stdio.h>
#include        <stdlib.h>
#include        <math.h>

#define         TAB     {697.0f, 770.0f, 852.0f, 941.0f, 1209.0f, 1336.0f, 1477.0f, 1633.0f}
#define         LEN     8

int             main(int ac, char **av)
{
  float         tab[LEN] = TAB;
  float         sr;

  if (ac >= 1)
    printf("Usage: ./a.out sample_rate\n");
  else
    sr = atof(av[1]);

  if (sr > 0)
    {
      printf("+-----------------------+-----------------------+\n");
      float coef = 0;
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < LEN; i++)
        {
          coef = cos(2.0f * 3.14159f * (tab[i] / sr)) * 256 * 128;
          printf("|     %f      |       %f      |\n", tab[i], coef);
          printf("+-----------------------+-----------------------+\n");
        }
    }
  else
    {
      printf("You cannot use a sample rate that is smaller or equal to 0\n");
      exit (0);
    }

}
```

You can use it like this:

```
gcc yourFile.c -lm && ./a.out 8000
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the comment in [this code](https://github.com/thienhaiblue/ampm_personal_tracker/blob/master/firmware/source/src/projects/project_main/DTMF.c):

```
// ----- Parameters and Variables for Tone Detector ----- 
// cos = (cos (2*PI*(DTMF_Freq/8000.0))) * 256*128;
#define DTMF_697Hz   27980        // DTMF Row Frequency
#define DTMF_770Hz   26956
#define DTMF_852Hz   25701
#define DTMF_941Hz   24219
#define DTMF_1209Hz  19073        // DTMF Column Frequency
#define DTMF_1336Hz  16325
#define DTMF_1477Hz  13085
#define DTMF_1633Hz   9315
#define DTMF_1394Hz  15014        // DTMF Row Frequency    2nd harm
#define DTMF_1540Hz  11583
#define DTMF_1704Hz   7549
#define DTMF_1882Hz   3032
#define DTMF_2418Hz -10565        // DTMF Column Frequency 2nd harm
#define DTMF_2672Hz -16503
#define DTMF_2954Hz -22318
#define DTMF_3266Hz -27472
```

It explains how the `cos_fact` is being calculated pretty directly. For example, for the first item in the list:

[$$
\cos( 2 \pi \times 697 / 8000) \times 256 \times 128 = 27979.5762684 \approx 27980
$$](https://www.google.com/search?ei=8db3XL6RGM2OggeGpqGAAQ&q=cos%282*pi*697%2F8000%29*256*128&oq=cos%282*pi*697%2F8000%29*256*128&gs_l=psy-ab.3...4906.10496..11387...0.0..0.101.531.5j1......0....1..gws-wiz.Xl6w40rj4g4)